# problem with the proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

please see here(p.174-175 [Elementary real and complex analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=UkQ8ANdjJUcC)
By Georgiĭ Evgenʹevich Shilov):

Image snapshot from google books:

[image]

Question is, why is $\displaystyle |H(z)| \lt 1/2$ true?

Comment: uh... I get "page 156 to 176 are not shown in this preview"

Comment: Google Book links are unstable and country-dependent. I cannot even see page 174 from where I am connecting right now.

Comment: Victor: I urge you to improve the quality of your questions. Try to make them *[self-contained](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48742/please-prove-laplaces-theorem-by-english-word-for-word-i-dont-know-where-to-sta)* and *[understandable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51464/please-give-me-a-counter-example-and-example-of-bounded-entire-function-that-is)*, please.

Comment: You have also posted it [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=418421&p2360294#p2360294).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the definition of continuity in $0$. For any $\epsilon$ you can find $\delta$ such as $z$ lies in the disc centered in $0$ with radius $\delta$ implies $H(z)$ is in the disc centered on $H(0)=0$ with radius $\epsilon=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

It follows from continuity of polynomials: If $H$ is continuus at $z_0$ then for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $r>0$ such that if $|z-z_0|<r$ then $|H(z)-H(z_0)|<\varepsilon$. 
Plug in $z_0=0$, $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and remember that $H(0)=0$.